# Windows file sharing problems when using nested routers

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, network-shares

My topology looks like this:

WAN
    - Router 1 (LAN 192.168.4.1; 255.255.255.0)
        - PC 1 (192.168.4.10)
        - Router 2 (WAN 192.168.4.20; LAN 192.168.3.1; 255.255.255.0)
            - PC 2 (192.168.3.10)

And I need to enable windows file sharing between PC 1 and PC 2. And when I go to "Network" in Win7 Explorer, I want to see my PC 1 and PC 2 there on both computers.

My Router 2 redirects ports 445 and 137-139 to PC 2. This way, I managed to get it working somewhat. I can access the PC 2 from PC 1 by entering IP directly "\\192.168.4.20\". But I cannot access the PC 2 from PC 1 by typing it's computer name, and I also don't see it in "Network". It goes the same when accessing PC 1 from PC 2 ... I can use IP, but not name.

I tried using DMZ on Router 2 but that did not helped one bit. I tried turning PC 2 Windows Firewall off, but that also did not helped. When both computers were connected to the same router, it all worked fine. But the topology changed recently. So how can I get it working again? Thanks.

PC 1 is Win7, PC 2 is WinVista.

Comment: Why is your network set up this way?! Why not flatten it? Dual NAT sucks. (Your setup is very broken. How would a packet from 192.168.4.20 to 192.168.3.10 ever get to router 2?)

Comment: Because some PCs don't have Wifi and the Wifi router (Router 1) is not accessible by multiple cables.

Comment: So why not connect the Internet access to router 2 and use router 1 just as a switch and access point? Or connect router 1's wired port to router 2's LAN port and connect other wired machines to router 2? Or something that makes sense.

Comment: Router 1 is also modem, I cannot move it around. To access Router 2 subnetwork, I just need to address Router 2 WAN address ... I need to get running the file sharing and other incoming connections are not required. But I would need to use port redirecting otherwise obviously.

Comment: So connect router 2's LAN port to router 1's wired port. Disable router 2's DHCP server. Connect wired machines to router 2's other LAN ports. You will never be happy with a dual-NAT setup.

Comment: Heh that sounds like a cool solution if that would work. But the funny thing is that all LAN ports of Router 2 are taken. I guess I would need to attach 3rd router to have enough ports and do this trick on both.

Comment: Some routers allow you to use their WAN port as an additional LAN port. What models are they? You could also use a switch, if you have one, to add more LAN ports.

Comment: The router 2 is Tenda W306R. Unfortunately I don't have a switch. I don't see the ability to use WAN port as additional LAN port anywhere in the options. :-( I guess I'm gonna need 3rd router.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Just wanted to tell you that your solution works. Even though having to use third router because I use 2 in the first place is not what I expected to be the solution, it works really well. Thanks. If you post your comment explaining how to connect the routers to LAN ports, I will accept it as an answer.

Comment: By the way, I've found a DD-WRT router home and I turned the WAN port into LAN port, so I use just 2 routers after all. Thanks again. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of double NAT. You can use routers as switches and access points by connecting them LAN-to-LAN.

Comment: Related discussion is in the comment section of the question.